# How to add conditional annotation from other column of R dataframe in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, highlight

I'm trying to make a plot from a dataframe of over 300k rows where the high and low values of Y will be annotated from another column rather than the x and y.
How can I do that..!!

Dataframe :

```
         chr   start   end.x     StoZ.x Hscore end.y StoZ.y Tier Gene
    1   chr1       1   10000  0.0000000      0    NA     NA <NA> <NA>
    2   chr1   10001   20000  3.6488202      2    NA     NA <NA> <NA>
    3   chr1   20001   30000 -0.8475483      0    NA     NA <NA> <NA>
    4   chr1   30001   40000  2.1279359      2    NA     NA <NA> <NA>
    5   chr1   40001   50000  1.4119515      0    NA     NA <NA> <NA>
        ................
        ................
        ................
  256   chr1 2550001 2560000 -2.363378       1 2560000 -2.363378 T1 TNFRSF14
  257   chr1 2560001 2570000 -0.796173       0 2570000 -0.796173 T1 TNFRSF14
       ................
       ................
       ................
  305   chr1 3040001 3050000 0.0564608       0 NA NA NA NA
  306   chr1 3050001 3060000 1.4822029       0 NA NA NA NA
  307   chr1 3060001 3070000 1.7718186       0 3070000 1.7718186 T1 PRDM16
  308   chr1 3070001 3080000 1.5650776       0 3080000 1.5650776 T1 PRDM16

       ................
       ................
       ................
```

[image]

Till now what I did,

```
 p2<-ggplot(BreastCanT1T2mer, aes(start, StoZ.x)) + 
      geom_jitter(aes(color =  Hscore), pch = 23, size = 0.2) +      
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("gray70","#525480","#9F5370","blue","red"), labels=c('NEUT', 'LOSS',  'GAIN', "DEL","AMP" ))+
      theme(legend.position = c(0.5, .06), legend.direction = "horizontal")+
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "black")+
      guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1.5)))+
      xlab("Chromosomes") + ylab("Stoffers-Z Score")+ 
      facet_wrap(~factor(chr, c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", "chr12", "chr13", "chr14","chr15", "chr16","chr17","chr18","chr19","chr20","chr21","chr22", "chrX", "chrY")), nrow =1, strip.position = "bottom") +
      theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0.1, "lines"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
      theme( legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA))
    p2
    
    p2+stat_peaks(span=7,size= 1, ignore_threshold = 0.95, color="brown")+
      stat_peaks(geom="text", size= 1.5, span=7, ignore_threshold = 0.95, color="red", angle=90, hjust=-0.1, check_overlap = TRUE) +
      stat_valleys(span=7,size= 1, ignore_threshold = 0.95, color="skyblue")+
      stat_valleys(geom="text",  size= 1.5, span=7, ignore_threshold = 0.95, color="black", angle=90, hjust=1.1, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

My expectation is that the Gene name will appear only once where the Gene is available (StoZ is probably highest and lowest) and where the StoZ value should be less than -10 or greater than +10.

**Improvement after @Elin's sugesstion

```
p2+geom_text(aes(label=Gene))
```

Here, the Name of the Genes should appear only once and y conditioned on <-2 and >+2.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using geom_text(aes(Gene))  ? If the NAs print then change them to "".

Comment: After doing 
p2+geom_text(aes(Gene))
it shows 
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Okay I see you figured out that ggrepel will help.

Comment: You may want to check package `ggrepel` (https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have so far is here, however, I believe the output may be better.

```
p2+geom_text_repel(aes(label= ifelse(StoZ.x < -20, unique(Gene), "")), size=1.5, angle = 45) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label= ifelse(StoZ.x > 20, unique(Gene), "")), size=1.5,  angle = 45)
```

[image]

Now I'm wondering if I can make geom_text color based `Tier` column.

So far, what I've done hasn't yielded the desired results. Because I have called `scale_color_manual` in `p2`, I can't call it here. So I'm attempting to use `scale_fill_manual`. but it's not working.
Hoping for advices.

```
p2+geom_text_repel(aes(label= ifelse(StoZ.x < -10, unique(Gene), ""), hjust = 1, vjust=.5, size=0.5, angle = 45), fill = as.factor(BreastCanT1T2mer$Tier)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("brown", "navy"))
```

Comment: Try using hjust = .5 and also vjust to move your labels over a bit.  Play around with the value to get something that works.  I think that keeping the faceting to 1 row is hurting readability.

Comment: Also if you must keep it one row, make it wider and assume that if you have it in the document that the page will be landscape.  Removing the "chr" from the strip labels will also make it less cluttered,

Comment: Thank you so much @Elin , for providing all those suggestions.